# os.path.exists not working properly on Python CLI

Tags: python, python-module

I've Python 2.5.x on my Windows 7 machine.

```
os.path.exists('C:')              # returns True
os.path.exists('C:\Users')        # returns True
os.path.exists('C:\Users\alpha')  # returns False, when ALPHA is a user on my machine
```

I've given read/write permissions to the CLI I'm using.
What could be the possible reason for this ?

Comment: @mac: partially. '\a'->'\x07' ; '\b'->'\x08' ; '\c'-> '\\c'; '\U' -> '\\U'; '\A'->'\\A'. These are a few examples of how python treats literals preceded by backslashes when in single quotes. What that means, I still don't know. Notice an edit in the question statement, since ALPHA was a fictitious user name. Had the user name been 'ALPHA' it would have worked correctly since '\A' translates to '\\A'. But '\a' translates to '\x07' which implies 'C:\Users\alpha' translates to 'C:\\Users\x07lpha' which is not a valid path on my machine.

Comment: oh for the love of god please stop using single backslashes.

Comment: @David: Just curious, what backslashes do in Python. Of course, not going to use them :)

Comment: you have good answers to that which you have not accepted.

Comment: @haltTm - Did you read the link to Python string literals? It explains the escape codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside quotes, '\' escapes the next character; see the [reference on string literals](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/strings.html). Either double your backslashes like:

```
os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\ALPHA')
```

to escape the backslashes themselves, use forward slashes as path separators as Michael suggests, or use "raw strings":

```
os.path.exists(r'C:\Users\ALPHA')
```

The leading `r` will cause Python not to treat the backslashes as escape characters. That's my favorite solution to dealing with Windows pathnames because they still look like people expect them to.

Answer (score 1):

Use either double backslashes, or forward slashes:

```
os.path.exists('C:/Users/ALPHA')
```

Comment: Apparently that should not be the issue. Repeating the comments from a question that might be deleted: `>>> x = 'C:\Users\ALPHA'`, -> `>>> x -> 'C:\\Users\\ALPHA'`